# How to get log for head of current branch?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-revsets

I can get the head of the current branch via

```
hg head .
```

I can then get the data I need by copying and pasting the changeset ID from the output of that command into this one:

```
'hg' 'log' --'limit' '1' --'style' 'xml' --'verbose' --'rev' 'ac99e18fbca1'
```

The problem is that I need to do this programatically, and I'd prefer not to parse the output of `hg head .`. So, can I either:

1. Do this with a single command? I couldn't find anything in [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) that would work.
2. Format `hg head .` to give me *just* the changeset ID?

Answer (score 2):

- You can use in log any usable cset-id, not only short-hash

Revset for `hg head .` (may produce more than one changeset in case of anonymous branching)

```
hg log -l 1 --style xml -v -r "heads(branch(.))"
```

is perfectly valid and always usable single command for your task

- For all log-style commands (including heads) output can be modified with `--template` and [template-keywords](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates)

Only changeset-hash in head output will be something like

```
hg head . --template "{node|short}\n"
```

Test-case:

Standard head

```
>hg head .
changeset:   39:dc3bad781bc5
tag:         tip
user:        Ray Bream <...>
date:        Fri Aug 16 16:35:17 2013 +0600
summary:     ***
```

Templated head for the same repo

```
>hg head . --template "{node|short}\n"
dc3bad781bc5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed `head` accepts the `--style` param.

```
hg head . --style xml --verbose
```